# cin a char into an int variable to stop a loop

Tags: c++, loops, char, int, cin

I would like to read numbers into a static array of fixed size 10, but the user can break the loop by entering character `E`.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int myArray[10];
    int count = 0;
    cout << "Enter upto 10 integers. Enter E to end" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter num " << i + 1 << ":";
        cin >> myArray[i];
        if (myArray[i] != 'E')
        {
            cout << myArray[i] << endl;
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << count << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

However, I get the following results while entering `E`:

```
Enter upto 10 integers. Enter E to end
Enter num 1:5
5
Enter num 2:45
45
Enter num 3:25
25
Enter num 4:2
2
Enter num 5:E
-858993460
Enter num 6:-858993460
Enter num 7:-858993460
Enter num 8:-858993460
Enter num 9:-858993460
Enter num 10:-858993460
10
Press any key to continue . . .
```

How can I fix this code in the simplest way?

Comment: Because cin fails to read a char into an `int`. You could read a string instead, and check if the first char is `'E'`.

Answer (score 0):

`cin` fails for parsing character `'E'` to `int`. The solution would be to read string from user check if it is not "E" (it is a string not a single char so you need to use double quotes) and then try to convert string to `int`. However, this conversion can throw exception (see below).

Easiest solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string> //for std::stoi function
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int myArray[10];
    int count = 0;
    cout << "Enter upto 10 integers. Enter E to end" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter num " << i + 1 << ":";
        std::string input;
        cin >> input;
        if (input != "E")
        {
            try
            {
                // convert string to int this can throw  see link below
                myArray[i] = std::stoi(input);
            }
            catch (const std::exception& e)
            {
                std::cout << "This is not int" << std::endl;
            }
            cout << myArray[i] << endl;
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << count << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

See [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) for `std::stoi`. It can throw exception so your program will end suddenly (by termination) that is why there is `try` and `catch` blocks around it. You will need to handle the case when user puts some garbage values in your string.

Answer (score 0):

If you debug this, you will find all your `myArray[i]` are `-858993460 (=0x CCCC CCCC)`, which is a value for the uninitialized variables in the stack.

When you put a `E` to an `int` variable `myArray[i]`. `std::cin` will set the state flag `badbit` to `1`.

Then when you run `cin >> myArray[i]`, it will skip it. In other words, do nothing.

Finally, you will get the result as above.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
char myArray[10];
```

because at the time of taking input console when get character then try to convert `char` to `int` which is not possible and store default value in `std::cin` i.e. 'E' to `0` (default value of int).

Use below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char myArray[10];
    int count = 0;
    cout << "Enter upto 10 integers. Enter E to end" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter num " << i + 1 << ":";
        cin >> myArray[i];
        if (myArray[i] == 'E')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << myArray[i] << endl;
            count++;
        }
    }
exitloop:
    cout << count << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter upto 10 integers. Enter E to end
Enter num 1:1
1
Enter num 2:E
1
sh: 1: PAUSE: not found
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if you enter a 2-digit or 3-digit number. char variables can only hold one symbol.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that attempting to read `E` as an `int` fails, and puts the stream in an error state where it stops reading (which you don't notice because it just doesn't do anything after that) and leaves your array elements uninitialized.

The simplest possible way is to break on any failure to read an integer:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter num " << i + 1 << ":";
    if (cin >> myArray[i])
    {
        cout << myArray[i] << endl;
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

If you want to check for `E` specifically, you need to read a string first, and then convert that to an `int` if it's not `E`.
As a bonus, you need to handle everything that's neither `int` nor `E`, which complicates the code a bit.
Something like this:

```
int count = 0;
string input;
while (cin >> input && count < 10)
{
    if (input == "E")
    {
        break;
    }
    istringstream is(input);
    if (is >> myArray[count])
    {
        cout << myArray[count] << endl;
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Please input an integer, or E to exit." << endl;
    }
}
```